# Is there any trick to getting the sneak attack materia

Tags: final-fantasy-7

From what I can tell, the only way to get the Sneak Attack materia is to win it as a prize in in A- and S-rank chocobo races. However, it never seems to show up as a prize for me, and when it does you can bet it isn't among the ones I win.

Is there any way to increase the odds of getting this materia? Alternately is there any place other than the Chocobo Races where you can find it?

Comment: Pretty sure the Gold Saucer part of the "100% speed run" category is a giant run killer. Still, WR for that is under 24 hours total (on PS2; much shorter on PC).

Answer (score 1):

I think the chances of getting the Sneak Materia from a win are around **1 in 60**.
**So keep playing your odds.**

Also, read somewhere that equipping your racer with the **Precious Watch** may boost your chances of winning it.

There is no other place where you can obtain it. Good luck!